# How to add excerpt and read more button to category archive page

Tags: categories, archives, excerpt, buttons

I am finding it hard to add excerpt and read more button to my category archive page

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. I really don't want to start you of badly, but have you done any research at all before posting? Please see [How to Ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what is expected from you and what is regarded as a good question. We do expect from you to have at least tried something, done some research.

Comment: Hi, @sven yes sure i d not navigate down to this site to ask for what I can't get elsewhere rather I asked cos it will be more of discussion based compared to all wish I have tried with no solution thanks